# Generator for splitting list (sequence) in N chunks in Python

Tags: python, list, generator

```
for i in generate_chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
    print(i)

# [[1], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
# [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5]]


for i in generate_chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3):
    print(i)

# [[1], [2], [3, 4, 5]]
# [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5]]
# [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5]]
# [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
# ...
```

**How can I implement `generate_chunks(list, n)`?**

Essentially what `generate_chunks` does is splitting `list` in `n` chunks and yield a list of these chunks.

For clarification, `n` refers to the *number* of chunks, not the *length* of the chunks.

The order in which those lists of chunks are yielded is irrelevant, however the order of the elements in the initial list is important, so that for a given list `[1, 2, 3]` the result `[[1], [2, 3]]` would be valid whereas `[[1], [3, 2]` would be invalid.

*(Preferably without using a 3rd-party library)*

Comment: Have you tried using `range` and adding the chunk size to each step as the end of the slice? like `for i in range(0, len(l), s)` and then `yield l[i, i+s]`

Comment: @arielnmz Assuming you mean `yield l[i : i+s]`. This returns `[1, 2] [3, 4] [5]` with `s = 2`

Comment: What should be the output of `generate_chunks(l,4)`?

Comment: Each 'yield' should return a list of length 4

Comment: By your previous examples, with a chunk size of 3, `[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5]]` do not appear to be chunks of length 3.

Comment: @arielnmz no, the OP does not really mean `chunk` size, they mean *number* of chunks

Comment: You are talking about chunks, but "all possible" sounds more like combinations. Either way, include itertools (which is not third party) in your search.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, that question includes permutations, the OP seems to just want them in the same order

Comment: @JoeIddon This is so confusing: *what generate_chunks does is splitting list in n chunks* -- *Each 'yield' should return a list of length 4*. What exactly is the rule for generating such chunks?

Comment: @arielnmz I agree! The question is unclear

Comment: I disagree with closing this as a duplicate. The other question is asking for *all* partitions into a given number of pieces. This is asking for just some of the partitions, those in which each piece consists of contiguous elements. Thus, I am voting to reopen.

Comment: @JohnColeman: I agree with you. Your answer shows that we have understood the question in the same way. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @John (and @Serge): I think you're mistaken about it not being a duplicate. The `sorted_k_partitions()` function near the beginning of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39199937/355230) generates the grouping desired by this question—try it yourself and see. It does unnecessarily sort the final result it returns, which isn't necessary here, but that does little harm.

Comment: @martineau I also think it's not a duplicate.  Briefly, that question accepts [(2,), (4,), (1, 3)] as a partition, but this one does not because 1 and 3 are not contiguous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) based approach:

```
import itertools

def chunks(items, cutpoints):
    return [items[i:j] for i,j in zip([0] + cutpoints, cutpoints + [len(items)])]

def generate_chunks(items, n):
    indices = range(1,len(items))
    for cutpoints in itertools.combinations(indices,n-1):
        yield chunks(items,list(cutpoints))
```

For example:

```
>>> for c in generate_chunks([1,2,3,4,5],4): print(c)

[[1], [2], [3], [4, 5]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4], [5]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4], [5]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta No you shouldn't if you read the question, the function takes the number of chunks to return so your example does not fit the input of `4` chunks