# Sub lists of list

Tags: python

I would like to have a function `split_list([1,2,4,3])` which yields the following 7 lists:

```
[[1], [2,4,3]]
[[1,2], [4,3]]
[[1,2,4], [3]]
[[1,2], [4],[3]]
[[1],[2,4],[3]]
[[1],[2],[4,3]]
[[1],[2],[4],[3]]
```

where the smaller lists are yielded first - `[[1], [2,4,3]]` has length 2 while `[[1],[2],[4],[3]]` is yielded last because its length is 4. This is as far as I have gotten with it:

```
def split_list(l):
  for i in range(1, len(l)):
    yield [l[:i],l[i:]]

for i in split_list((1,2,4,3)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: What do you mean by smaller lists?

Comment: @RobS The length of [[1], [2,4,3]] is 2 while the length of [[1],[2],[4],[3]] is 4.

Comment: maybe dupe: [How to find all partitions of a list S into k subsets (can be empty)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53937159/674039)

Comment: or: [How to split a list into n groups in all possible combinations of group length and elements within group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39192777/674039)

Comment: or: [Show all possible groupings of a list, given only the amount of sublists (lengths are variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9088321/674039)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a list into n groups in all possible combinations of group length and elements within group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192777/how-to-split-a-list-into-n-groups-in-all-possible-combinations-of-group-length-a)

Comment: Do you want the sub-lists in that specific order?

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo No, as long as the lists yielded get larger

Comment: Do you want to exclude the main list as the first element? For example [[1, 2, 3, 4]]

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize list slicing with recursion:

```
def split_list(d):
   for i in range(len(d)):
      if len(d[i+1:]) > 0:
        for c in split_list(d[i+1:]):
          yield [d[:i+1], *c]
      else:
        yield [d]

print(list(split_list([1,2,4,3])))
```

Output:

```
[[[1], [2], [4], [3]], [[1], [2], [4, 3]], [[1], [2, 4], [3]], [[1], [2, 4, 3]], [[1, 2], [4], [3]], [[1, 2], [4, 3]], [[1, 2, 4], [3]], [[1, 2, 4, 3]]]
```

**Edit: event shorter**

```
def split_list(d):
  if len(d) > 1:
    return [list(filter(None, [d[:i+1], *c])) for i in range(len(d)) for c in split_list(d[i+1:])]
  return [d] if not isinstance(d, list) else [[d]]
```

Output:

```
[[[1], [2], [4], [3]], [[1], [2], [4, 3]], [[1], [2, 4], [3]], [[1], [2, 4, 3]], [[1, 2], [4], [3]], [[1, 2], [4, 3]], [[1, 2, 4], [3]], [[1, 2, 4, 3]]]
```

Comment: Nice!! What does the * in *c do? unpack the list?

Comment: @RobS Yes, that is correct. `*c` is simple unpacking. I think it is a bit cleaner (although that is somewhat subjective) that concatenating lists with `+`.

Answer (score 1):

If including the list itself as the first element is not a problem, you could so something like this:

```
def split_list(lst):
    if not lst:
        yield []

    for i in range(len(lst), 0, -1):
        for j in split_list(lst[i:]):
            yield [lst[:i]] + j


for l in split_list([1, 2, 4, 3]):
    print(l)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 4, 3]]
[[1, 2, 4], [3]]
[[1, 2], [4, 3]]
[[1, 2], [4], [3]]
[[1], [2, 4, 3]]
[[1], [2, 4], [3]]
[[1], [2], [4, 3]]
[[1], [2], [4], [3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
def split_list(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        yield [ l ]
        return

    for s in split_list(l[1:]):
        for n, sub in enumerate(s):
            if len((s[:n] + [[ l[0] ] + sub]  + s[n+1:])[0]) !=4:
                yield s[:n] + [[ l[0] ] + sub]  + s[n+1:]           
        yield [[l[0]]] + s

for lst in split_list([1, 2, 3, 4]):
        print lst
```

The problem is solved recursively.
And in output:

```
[[1], [2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[2], [1, 3, 4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4]]
[[2, 3], [1, 4]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4]]
[[1, 3], [2, 4]]
[[3], [1, 2, 4]]
[[1], [3], [2, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4]]
[[2], [1, 3], [4]]
[[2], [3], [1, 4]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```