# How can I solve this problem using itertools?

Tags: python, python-itertools

Hello I have tried using this tool:

```
list(combinations('01', 3))
```

but I get this result:

```
[]
```

I would like to have these results:

```
000
001
011
111
101
100
010
```

Separately, I would also like to have different cases.

for instance, given `111` I expect these results:

```
111
12
21
3
```

Is it possible to do these two things using `itertools`?

Comment: Where does the `3` comes from?

Comment: The keyword you're missing for your searches is "partitioning".  You haven't sufficiently described your problem, but it looks as if you want to partition the outputs into groups and sum the groups.

Comment: 3 is the sum of 111

Comment: Seems like something similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192777/how-to-split-a-list-into-n-groups-in-all-possible-combinations-of-group-length-a

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which is partially using the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30134039/11608064).

- The partition function from alexis' answer (see link)
  returns the list partitioned into groups (i.e. [[[1,1,1]],[[1,1],[1]],[[1],[1,1]],[[1],[1],[1]]]
- To get the numbers in your question, I added a part that stores only the sum of each inner list
- list(dict.fromkeys(...)) is used to remove duplicates

### Code

```
def partition(collection):
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield [ collection ]
        return

    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in partition(collection[1:]):
        # insert `first` in each of the subpartition's subsets
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            yield smaller[:n] + [[ first ] + subset]  + smaller[n+1:]
        # put `first` in its own subset 
        yield [ [ first ] ] + smaller


elements = list([1,1,1])

lst = list(dict.fromkeys([ tuple([sum(p[1][i]) for i in range(len(p[1]))]) for p in enumerate(partition(elements), 1) ]))

print(sorted(lst))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3,)]
```

Comment: If you want it to print as `111 12 21 3`, you can do `print(' '.join([''.join([str(i) for i in j]) for j in lst]))`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking two separate questions.  Based on your results:

1. > 000 001 011 111 101 100 010

Use a [*permutations_with_replacement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition) combinatoric via [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

2. > 111 12 21 3

Use a [*partitions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) algorithm via [`more_itertools.partitions`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.partitions).

**Given**

```
import itertools as it

import more_itertools as mit
```

**Code**

```
# 1 - Permutation w Replacement
>>> list(it.product("01", repeat=3))
[('0', '0', '0'),
 ('0', '0', '1'),
 ('0', '1', '0'),
 ('0', '1', '1'),
 ('1', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '0', '1'),
 ('1', '1', '0'),
 ('1', '1', '1')]
```

```
# 2 - Partitions
>>> list(mit.partitions("111"))
[[['1', '1', '1']],
 [['1'], ['1', '1']],
 [['1', '1'], ['1']],
 [['1'], ['1'], ['1']]]
```

---

**Details**

To achieve your specific results, use list comprehensions:

```
# 1
>>> ["".join(x) for x in it.product("01", repeat=3)]

['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

```
# 2
>>> [[sum(map(int, x)) for x in sub] for sub in mit.partitions("111")]

[[3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party package.  Install with `> pip install more-itertools`.