# How to split a list into n groups in all possible combinations of group length and elements within group in R?

Tags: r

My goal is to divide a list into n groups in all possible combinations (where the group has a variable length).

I found the same question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192777/how-to-split-a-list-into-n-groups-in-all-possible-combinations-of-group-length-a) (Python environment), but I'm unable to replicate it in the R environment.

Could anyone kindly help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an easy implementation for the similar objective, you can try `listParts` from package `partitions`, e.g.,

```
> x <- 4

> partitions::listParts(x)
[[1]]
[1] (1,2,3,4)

[[2]]
[1] (1,2,4)(3)

[[3]]
[1] (1,2,3)(4)

[[4]]
[1] (1,3,4)(2)

[[5]]
[1] (2,3,4)(1)

[[6]]
[1] (1,4)(2,3)

[[7]]
[1] (1,2)(3,4)

[[8]]
[1] (1,3)(2,4)

[[9]]
[1] (1,4)(2)(3)

[[10]]
[1] (1,2)(3)(4)

[[11]]
[1] (1,3)(2)(4)

[[12]]
[1] (2,4)(1)(3)

[[13]]
[1] (2,3)(1)(4)

[[14]]
[1] (3,4)(1)(2)

[[15]]
[1] (1)(2)(3)(4)
```

where `x` is the number of elements in the set, and all partitions denotes the indices of elements.

---

If you want to choose the number of partitions, below is a user function that may help

```
f <- function(x, n) {
  res <- listParts(x)
  subset(res, lengths(res) == n)
}
```

such that

```
> f(x, 2)
[[1]]
[1] (1,2,4)(3)

[[2]]
[1] (1,2,3)(4)

[[3]]
[1] (1,3,4)(2)

[[4]]
[1] (2,3,4)(1)

[[5]]
[1] (1,4)(2,3)

[[6]]
[1] (1,2)(3,4)

[[7]]
[1] (1,3)(2,4)


> f(x, 3)
[[1]]
[1] (1,4)(2)(3)

[[2]]
[1] (1,2)(3)(4)

[[3]]
[1] (1,3)(2)(4)

[[4]]
[1] (2,4)(1)(3)

[[5]]x
[1] (2,3)(1)(4)

[[6]]
[1] (3,4)(1)(2)
```

---

**Update**
Given `x <- LETTERS[1:4]`, we can run

```
res <- rapply(listParts(length(x)), function(v) x[v], how = "replace")
```

such that

```
> res
[[1]]
[1] (A,B,C,D)

[[2]]
[1] (A,B,D)(C)

[[3]]
[1] (A,B,C)(D)

[[4]]
[1] (A,C,D)(B)

[[5]]
[1] (B,C,D)(A)

[[6]]
[1] (A,D)(B,C)

[[7]]
[1] (A,B)(C,D)

[[8]]
[1] (A,C)(B,D)

[[9]]
[1] (A,D)(B)(C)

[[10]]
[1] (A,B)(C)(D)

[[11]]
[1] (A,C)(B)(D)

[[12]]
[1] (B,D)(A)(C)

[[13]]
[1] (B,C)(A)(D)

[[14]]
[1] (C,D)(A)(B)

[[15]]
[1] (A)(B)(C)(D)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to decide the n groups? for example with n = 2 we have:

[(1), (2,3,4)]
[(2), (1,3,4)]
[(3), (1,2,4)]
[(4), (1,2,3)]
[(1,2), (3,4)]
[(1.3), (2.4)]
[(1.4), (2.3)]

while with n = 3

[(1), (2), (3,4)]
[(1), (3), (2.4)]
[(1), (4), (2,3)]
[(2), (3), (1.4)]
[(2), (4), (1,3)]
[(3), (4), (1,2)]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much again !!

Comment: if I have a character vector like this x <- LETTERS(1:4) instead of a vector x <- 4 how can I perform the same combination?

Comment: @GN_Agostino I updated my answer, where `rapply` is used.