# How to get all possible combinations of dividing a list of length n into m sublists

Tags: python, list, combinatorics

In my specific case I would like to get all possible combinations of dividing a list of length 20 into 4 sublists. The sublists may have any length from 1 to 17. As a result I would like to have a list of lists of sublists with all possible combinations.

List to start with:

```
list_init = [a, b,  c,  d,  e,  f,  g,  h,  i,  j,  k,  l,  m,  n,  o,  p,  q,  r,  s,  t]
```

List of lists of lists with all combinations:

```
list_combs = [
[[a],   [b],    [c],    [d, e,  f,  g,  h,  i,  j,  k,  l,  m,  n,  o,  p,  q,  r,  s,  t]],
[[a,d], [b],    [c],    [e, f,  g,  h,  i,  j,  k,  l,  m,  n,  o,  p,  q,  r,  s,  t]],
[[a,d,e],   [b],    [c],    [f, g,  h,  i,  j,  k,  l,  m,  n,  o,  p,  q,  r,  s,  t]],
.
.
.
]
```

Comment: what problems have you had so far? where is your own code? Note that SO is not a coding service and your post unintentionally comes off as asking for a service rather than a question to particular problem in your own code.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192777 for the case where outputs with lists in a different order should not be considered distinct.

Comment: Better for that purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that recursively by combining a first part of length 1,2,3,... with the partitions in 3 of the rest (recursing to 2 and 1):

```
from itertools import combinations
def partCombo(L,N=4):
    if N==1: yield [L]; return
    for size in range(1,len(L)-N+2):
        for combo in combinations(range(len(L)),size): # index combinations
            part      = list(L[i] for i in combo)      # first part
            remaining = list(L)
            for i in reversed(combo): del remaining[i] # unused items
            yield from ([part]+rest for rest in partCombo(remaining,N-1))
```

output:

```
aList = list("abcdefg")
for part in partCombo(aList):
    print(part)

[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['d'], ['c', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['e'], ['c', 'd', 'f', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['f'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['g'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'e'], ['d', 'f', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'g'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['d', 'e'], ['c', 'f', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['d', 'f'], ['c', 'e', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['d', 'g'], ['c', 'e', 'f']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['e', 'f'], ['c', 'd', 'g']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['e', 'g'], ['c', 'd', 'f']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['f', 'g'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g']]
... and many more ... (total 8400)
```

For a list of 20 items, there will be 1,085,570,781,624 combinations.

```
from math import factorial
def countCombos(L,N=4):
    if N==1: return 1
    result = 0
    for size in range(1,L-N+2):
        c = factorial(L)//factorial(size)//factorial(L-size)
        c *= countCombos(L-size,N-1)
        result += c
    return result

sum(1 for _ in partCombo("abcdefg"))    # 8400
sum(1 for _ in partCombo("abcdefghij")) # 818520

countCombos(7)  # 8400 
countCombos(10) # 818520
countCombos(15) # 1016542800
countCombos(20) # 1085570781624
```

With that many combinations (of 20 items), it will be impossible to output a list of of all the combinations (it would never fit in memory).  This is why the function is written as a generator.  Still, it would take a long time (weeks) to go through all the combinations produced by the generator function on a list of 20 items.

Comment: thanks for providing a first try. however there are missing some combinations, such as:

Comment: For example this combination is missing: (['a', 'g'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'])

Comment: I adjusted the function to produce combinations within the partitions

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to deciding which list each element should go into (for example, by [picking a number from 0 to 3, 20 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987)), building each list of lists, and rejecting the ones which contain empty lists.

So, we can write a generator like:

```
from itertools import product

def partitions_of(elements, list_count):
    element_count = len(elements)
    for list_ids in product(range(list_count), repeat=element_count):
        if len(set(list_ids)) != list_count:
            continue # this combination would have an empty list.
        result = [[] for _ in range(list_count)]
        for list_id, element in zip(list_ids, elements):
            result[list_id].append(element)
        yield result
```

Testing it:

```
>>> for p in partitions_of('abcd', 2):
...     print(p)
... 
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']]
[['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
[['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b']]
[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
[['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c']]
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
[['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a']]
[['b', 'c'], ['a', 'd']]
[['b', 'd'], ['a', 'c']]
[['b'], ['a', 'c', 'd']]
[['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]
[['c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
[['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

As long as the number of input elements is large compared to the number of lists, relatively few candidates should get rejected. In the worst case, where there are as many lists as elements, such that we effectively permute the list and put each element in its own list, this will take O(N^N) time to compute O(N!) results, i.e., still exponentially slower (as implied by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)) than it needs to be.